# How to model a standardized index in a regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, data-transformation, standardization

I have a standardized index, $x$ (variations in s.d.) and I want to regress my dependent variable, $y$ on it.
In my dataset, the index ranges from approximately -2 to 2, but there is no constraint.
From a theoretical point of view, the higher the index, the higher should be the value of the dependent variable. So, I could just include the index in its natural form:

$y = \beta_0 +\beta_1x$

However, extreme positive values, can affect the dependent variable NEGATIVELY, as well, a classical case to include the $x^2$, but the fact the $x$ has negative values, puts a problem on it, right?

Can I do simple transformations, like $x_t = x+3$ or $x_t = ln(x+3)$ and then run
$y = \beta_0 +\beta_1x_t +\beta_2x_t^2$ ? What are the implications on that?

Comment: linearly rescaling x (so as to avoid negative values) will not change the regression of y on x with or without x²

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one caveat, there's no problem doing anything you would do with a regular variable to an index. After all, some 'regular' variables are indexes to start with. So as @patrick-coulombe notes, it'll be fine.

The caveat is that your index is probably not just a z-scored ordinary variable but actually an attempt at measuring a thing from a bunch of items, e.g. economic status from income and housing information or political position from a few survey questions.

In that case then the thing you really want is $x^*$ and you (or someone else)  averaged a bunch of other things to create $x$ which we hope is a good measure of $x^*$. In this case, there is probably some slippage between $x$ and $x^*$ which we can think of as error. So you have a variable "measured with error".

There are tools for dealing with measurement error in independent variables. Those might be worth investigating. In the simple scenario you describe in the question there is one index and one $y$, so we can usually (depending on how the index got made) conclude that the effect of increasing variance of $x$ around $x^*$ will be to shrink your estimate of $\beta_1$ relative to what it would have been if you'd plugged $x^*$ in instead.